# Rails STI cannot access methods of Base Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I cannot access the methods of the Base class when using STI approach in Rails 4

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    def do_something
      doing_something
    end
end

class Admin < User

end
```

and in the rails console I wanted to call

```
Admin.first.do_something     #  undefined method `do_something' for <Admin:0x00000005711510>
```

but this works

```
User.first.do_something
```

does anybody have an idea how I can access the base class methods when using Rails STI

Comment: Did you try to relaunch rails console?

Comment: I can't replicate this behavior.  Any more clues?

Comment: yes I more then once already... also irb_reloading is activated

Comment: actually i have the same problems with associations too .. i have to move them all into Admin (and some other User subclasses) as they are not accessible from them

Comment: Unless your ```do_something``` is underneath a ```private``` keyword in user.rb?

Comment: Also, I was able to replicate the behavior by defining the Admin class in the console first, then adding a ```foo``` method to User, and then trying to use reload to gain access to the ```foo``` method (I got a NoMethodError).

Comment: actually I think the private was the clue :S thanks a lot .. the class is already very big .. we should use the other approach of using private then just putting the keyword ...